# Clear a particular column of data table in vb

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datarow

[image]I have a data table which has 3 columns . I am populating the values of each column separately in a loop which causes the table structure to be in the format as shown in the image. How to clear every column at the beginning of the loop so that all data comes in a proper tabular format. In short I want to have **a data table with variable number of rows possible for each column**.

Comment: Kindly add the image..

Comment: @steve simon Please provide image

Comment: sorry.. have added the image

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Hi @stevesimon, without your code, the help we can offer is limited. We cannot see in which part of your code is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To clear every column at beginning of the loop you have two options:

1. loop all rows
2. remove column, add column

Depending on the plenty of rows the two options have different performances.
For large amount of rows i prefer the second option.